# DRF multi fields base match filter queryset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, drf-queryset

- I'm creating a **search functionality** where we can search based of `first_name`, `last_name`, `username`.it should filter all matches( if at least anyone fields match it should consider ) users except login users.
- this is what I have done but I'm searching for an efficient Django queryset.

  ```
  if search_name is not None and len(search_name) >= 3:

                  search_obj_1 = User.objects.filter(first_name__iexact=search_name).exists()
                  search_obj_2 = User.objects.filter(last_name__iexact=search_name).exists()

                  if search_obj_1:
                      search_obj_1 = User.objects.filter(Q(first_name__iexact=search_name)) &User.objects.filter(~Q(id=logged_user_id))
                      search_obj_2 = User.objects.filter(Q(last_name__iexact=search_name)) & User.objects.filter(~Q(id=logged_user_id))
                      search_obj_3 = []
                      search_obj = list(chain(search_obj_1, search_obj_2, search_obj_3))

                  elif search_obj_2:
                      search_obj_1 = []
                      search_obj_2 = User.objects.filter(
                          Q(last_name__iexact=search_name)) & User.objects.filter(~Q(id=logged_user_id))
                      search_obj_3 = User.objects.filter(
                          Q(username__iexact=search_name)) & User.objects.filter(~Q(id=logged_user_id))
                      search_obj = list(
                          chain(search_obj_2, search_obj_3, search_obj_1))

                  else:
                      search_obj_1 = []
                      search_obj_2 = []
                      search_obj_3 = User.objects.filter(
                          Q(username__iexact=search_name)) & User.objects.filter(~Q(id=logged_user_id))
                      search_obj = list(
                          chain(search_obj_3, search_obj_1, search_obj_2))
  ```
- so is there any better way do the same thing.

Comment: what is the purpose of this `len(search_name) >= 3`

Comment: search will work if the search key is more then 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this (using the [union operator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#or) `|`) :

```
search_obj = User.objects.exclude(id=logged_user_id).filter(
    Q(first_name__iexact=search_name)
    | Q(last_name__iexact=search_name)
    | Q(username__iexact=search_name)
)
```